# Swagger not giving UI for Spring MVC Project

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am new to the `Swagger` and trying to implement it in the `Spring MVC`. I'm using latest dependency `swagger-springmvc` from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc. So based on link https://dzone.com/articles/documenting-your-spring-api. I added following configuration in `mvc-config.xml`.

```
<!-- Serve static content - required for Swagger -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- to enable the default documentation controller-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers"/>

    <!-- to pick up the bundled spring configuration-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration"/>

    <!-- Direct static mappings -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="/, classpath:/swagger-ui"/>
```

Also I used following from link shown above.

```
<bean class="com.xxx.xx.xx.SwaggerConfig"/>
```

Then I added

```
git clone https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui
cp -r swagger-ui/dist ~/dev/x-auth-security/src/main/webapps/docs
```

When I launch the site: `http://localhost:8080/dp-rest/api-docs` I don't see UI format, it only gives JSON format.

```
{"apiVersion":"1.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/default/student-service","description":"Manage Student Service","position":0},{"path":"/default/student-service","description":"Manage Student Service","position":0}],"authorizations":[],"info":{"title":"Student API's","description":"API for Student ","termsOfServiceUrl":"terms.html","contact":"test@yahoo.com","license":"Commercial Proprietary","licenseUrl":"http://www.adbc.com"}}
```

Ny

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig {
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig) {
        this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    // Don't forget the @Bean annotation
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo()).includePatterns(".*");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("Student API", "API for Student",
                "term.html", "test@tahoo.com",
                "Commercial Proprietary", "http://www.test.com");
    }
}
```

Why UI format not coming when we launch the http://localhost:8080/sample-rest/api-docs site?
Then only I see raw JSON response not any ui, What is missing here? What I need to changed/add/modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

According to the article you'll see a section that tells you where to find the documentation. I'm not sure if you're using spring-boot but...

> After making these changes, I was able to open fire up the app with "mvn spring-boot:run" and view http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html in my browser.

In any case, swagger-springmvc is now called [springfox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/) and supports the latest swagger specification (2.0). There is also [documentation available](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/) to help you get started. I would recommend using the [latest version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2) (2.3.1 as of this writing) of springfox instead.